# Plivo always ask to verified my number even I already upgrade my account

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, plivo

I just pay my plivo account from trial to paid one and add the credit to use
but when I put the auth and token id to my system plivo always ask me to verified my number on sandbox even my account already upgraded.

here the result

```
POST /generateverif 200 96.249 ms - 4
Status:  400
API Response:
 { api_id: 'd5581123-347c-11e6-a170-22000aexxxxx',
  error: 'Destination Phone Numbers need to be verified. Please go to https://manage.plivo.com/sandbox-numbers/ to verify them.' }
Message UUID:
 undefined
Api ID:
 d5581123-347c-11e6-a170-22000aexxxx
```

I tried contact their customer support but no respond until today
any idea guys

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are on the Trial account, in order to overcome this issue, you'd need to upgrade your Plivo account by recharging a minimum of $25.

You can find more information about trial vs standard account from their [FAQ](https://support.plivo.com/hc/en-us/sections/360008303751-Free-Trial-Account)

Answer (score 0):

If send me an email (charlie at plivo.com) with your Plivo username and/or the support ticket number I can help you out.

Comment: I have the same problem. How to sort this out?

Comment: I don't work there anymore but I bet support@plivo.com would be a good first step

Comment: there support teams v good!